# why is this for loop affecting a variable outside loop?

Tags: c

I was doing an assignment, tried simplifying code with same results.

```
unsigned char x=5;
byte a1[100];
/*byte a1 is then filled*/
byte a2[7];
int counter = 0;

for (counter=0;counter!=8;counter++)
{
a2[counter]=a1[counter];
printf("%d ",x);
}
```

result is 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ?
where ? is a random number

i'm confused why this is happening as the arrays do not even relate to this variable, and it seems that everything is in range for arrays. what could be causing this or how can i solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're writing past the end of the array. Writing to `a2[7]` is undefined behaviour (and in your case, it wrote to the variable immediately after the array on the stack).

To fix this, either end the loop at 7 or declare `byte a2[8];`.

Answer (score 0):

As James pointed, you probably wanted to write:

```
for (counter = 0; counter < 7; counter++)
{
    a2[counter] = a1[counter];
    printf("%d ", x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare

```
byte a1 = [100];
```

That is not an array, it is saying a single byte is equal to [100]. I'm not sure why it compiles for you, that's not a valid way to declare a value.

Anyhow, it should be

```
byte a1[100];
```

In addition you're looping past the end of your array, as others have pointed out.

If you're unsure as to why, an 7-byte array starts counting from 0. So there are these positions:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6

There is no position 7

Comment: you are right, i mistyped it, i saw the same error for the other one but forgot to change this heh, the real error was first posted by james though